# getting the post_id from the post_meta

Tags: post-meta

I need to find out the post_id of a post_meta record where the custom key is 'XYZ' and the is 'ABC'? Is there an API for that?

Or do I need to run a regular select SQL with wpdb class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) in this case ...

```
$my_query = new WP_Query( array( 'meta_key' => 'XYZ', 'meta_value' => 'ABC' ) );

$post_ids = array();
while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
    $my_query->next_post();
    $post_ids[] = $my_query->post->ID;
}

wp_reset_postdata();
```

... and [read on here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts).

Answer (score 0):

Does something like this work?

```
query_posts('meta_key=XYZ&meta_value=ABC');
if (have_posts()) :
    while (have_posts()) : the_post();
        $post_id = get_the_ID() ;
        echo $post_id;
    endwhile;
else :
    echo 'Nothing';
endif;
```

Comment: Thank you but, I was more interested in a direct API. I ended up running a straight forward SQL select and get to the post ID thus; `SELECT post_id FROM wp_postmeta where `meta_key`='XYZ' and `meta_value`='ABC'